# Java. Need assistance with adding up the numbers for pig game

Tags: java, math, integer

I am coding a pig game in Java, and I need help adding up the score. The game's goal is to roll two dice, and the values of those two dice are added together, and the player who gets to 100 first wins. I want to loop the values (which I called "Added") so that it continuously adds up by themselves.
Thank you in advance
By the way, I'm hardly done most of the game, so mind the gaps, lol.

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pig {

    static int player, Continue, roll1, roll2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        Random r2 = new Random();

        System.out.print("Enter 1 to play against computer\nEnter 2 to play against another person\n");
        player = keyboard.nextInt();


        if (player == 1) {
            System.out.println("\nPlaying against the computer...");
            roll1 = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("\nYour first roll is a " + roll1);
            roll2 = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("\nYour second roll is a " + roll2);
            int added = roll1 + roll2;
            System.out.println("\nYour total is " + added);
            if ((roll1 == 1) || (roll2 == 1)) {
                System.out.println("\nYou rolled a 1, you lose all your points!");
            }

            System.out.print("\nEnter 1 to continue rolling\nEnter 2 to give up the dice\n");
            Continue = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (Continue == 1) {
                do {
                    roll1 = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
                    System.out.println("\nYour first roll is a " + roll1);
                    roll2 = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
                    System.out.println("\nYour second roll is a " + roll2);
                    int added2 = roll1 + roll2;
                    int added3 = added + added2;
                    added = added2;
                    added2 = added3;
                    System.out.println("\nYour total is " + added3);
                    if ((roll1 == 1) || (roll2 == 1)) {
                        System.out.println("\nYou rolled a 1, you lose all your points!");
                    }
                    System.out.print("\nEnter 1 to continue rolling\nEnter 2 to give up the dice\n");
                    Continue = keyboard.nextInt();
                } while (Continue == 1);
            }


        } else {
            System.out.print("Bye");

        }
                   
                    /*if (player == 2){
                   System.out.println("Playing against another person...");
                      }
                    else {
                          System.out.print("Bye");
                          count++;
                     */
    }


}
```

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting, it's my first time using this website

Comment: You haven't explained what your question is.

Comment: I want the score to continuously add up everytime I roll the dice. The problem is that right now the program only adds up the score to a certain amount. Currently I have to make a new variable everytime the dice is rolled so that the score increases. I need help looping the variables in a way, so that  I don't have to keep making a new variable every single time.

Comment: I've formatted your code for you, but please learn how to use your IDE to do that, it will make your life better.

Comment: Why don't you simply add `roll1` and `roll2` to `added`? And remove `added2` and `added3`?